# UIButton to forward events & retrieve values according to UIButton

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

I have a for loop that displays 7 UIButton all with a method pointing to the same view ( for loop , thats why) .

What i want is that when for 
e.g ,i click on button1 , the next view will display values that belongs to button1 .
and when i click on button2 , the next view (same view again) will display values that belongs to button2.

Any idea on how to work on that?

I have classes and appDelegate to store this values in it

Edit:
my UIButton is programmatically created, i cannot link IBAction to it. I think a few have mistaken about my question.

Comment: Do you know how to send data to a view and display that view accordingly? Or do you need help with that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, When you are looping for button, at that time, give tag value to button. And create one method like below:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender{
    int clickedTag = [sender tag];
}
```

inside that, you will get the Tag of button which is clicked. And you can do according to Tag.

Just set the tag while you are creating the buttons programmatically.

```
[button setTag:counter]; // if you are creating the buttons in For loop
```

Cheers.

Comment: i am programmatically created a UIButton, how to go about doing that?

Comment: For that, you can add below line.    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all these buttons probably have the same action, right? Give each button a different value for its `tag` property. The action can then look at the `tag` of the object that sent the message, e.g. `sender.tag`, to figure out which button was tapped. Use that information to figure out what data to display in the next view.

Comment: how do i do that?
button.tag = i+1; ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Set the tag value for all the buttons. Use the sender object to display the values accordingly in your view.